# Trouble loading rsample

Tags: r

I want to use rsample, so I first installed it using the code `install.packages("rsample")`. Up to here there was no problem, but when I entered `library("rsample")` what I get is an error message that says

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsample’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
```

What might be the issue here and how should I fix it?

Comment: Start a new session, install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE), to update dplyr, then try library('rsample') and see if it's happy.

Answer (score -1):

From time to time you should execute `update.packages()`.